# How do I get collapsible navigation bar to work?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

I'm using twitter bootstrap and I see the image below when I reduce the width of the browser window to a certain size.  However, when I click on it and nothing happens.  I normally have 2 elements there but can't see them when I width is too small.  How do I fix this by either removing the button from showing or have the button show but then show the 2 items on click?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To stop the button from displaying, you may add below code to your css:

```
.navbar .btn-navbar{
    display:none;
    }
```

Additionally , you may [go through this article](http://taylor.fausak.me/2012/03/15/dropdown-menu-in-twitter-bootstraps-collapsed-navbar/) for more information and help..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have responsive bootstrap css and the collapse javascript plugin per the bootstrap documentation:

> Heads up! The responsive navbar requires the collapse plugin and
>   responsive Bootstrap CSS file.

Also here is an example of it working (has bootstrap responsive css and bootstrap js referenced):
http://jsfiddle.net/ZdVcg/

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar">
<div class="navbar-inner">
<div class="container">

  <!-- .btn-navbar is used as the toggle for collapsed navbar content -->
  <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </a>

  <!-- Be sure to leave the brand out there if you want it shown -->
  <a class="brand" href="#">Project name</a>

  <!-- Everything you want hidden at 940px or less, place within here -->
  <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
    <!-- .nav, .navbar-search, .navbar-form, etc -->
      <ul class="nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      </ul>

  </div>

</div>
</div>
</div>​
```